# Tasks NameError: name 'cycle' is not defined discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks`
```

```
status = cycle(['status1','status2'])`
```

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print('Bot online')
```

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=3600)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next))
```

cycle won't work. could not find an easy fix I'm new to coding as a whole sorry for my noob-esh behavior I would love an answer tho,

my error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\OneDrive\Documents\3mbot\main code\mbot.py", line 20, in <module>
    status = cycle(['status1','status2',
NameError: name 'cycle' is not defined
```

Comment: `from itertools import cycle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cycle is in the itertools module.

```
from itertools import cycle
```

Comment: yeah, I did not think of that. this an old script. it seemed to work 4 months ago.